# HTML5 context.drawImage() crop is not working after calling context.translate()

Tags: javascript, html

[image: full image][image: 10 individual canases that correspond to areas of full image, WHAT I AM TRYING TO DO]> What I want here are 10 canvases, 5 on the top and 5 on the bottom, each with width 17% and height 25.5%, and appropriate spacing between (see bottom image). Each image drawn on a canvas corresponds to the same area of the full image (see top image). This is kind of like a destination-in, but this is really just a crop of the full image onto smaller canvases using context.translate and context.drawImage(). Please see the two lines inside the innermost for loop with comments that deal wtih context.translate and context.drawImage for clue as to what might be going on.

Please see the attached image of what I am trying to achieve with html5 context.translate() and context.drawImage().

Any help greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```js
    //get parent's width and height 
 var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
 var parentWidth = parent.offsetWidth;
 var parentHeight = parent.offsetHeight;
 
 //get below canvas
 var belowCanvas = document.getElementById('belowCanvas');
 var belowCtx = belowCanvas.getContext('2d');
 
 //create temporary canvas
 var tmpCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
 var tmpCtx = tmpCanvas.getContext('2d');
 
 //initialize width and height of temporary canvas and below canvas to equal parent
 tmpCanvas.width = belowCanvas.width = parentWidth;
 tmpCanvas.height = belowCanvas.height = parentHeight;
 
 //draw below canvas in black for visual aid of how things are cropped in above canvases
 belowCtx.rect(0,0,parentWidth,parentHeight);
 belowCtx.fillStyle = 'black';
 belowCtx.fill();
 
 //draw temporary canvas
 var centerX = parentWidth/4;
 var centerY = parentHeight/4;
 var radius = parentHeight/4;
 
 tmpCtx.rect(0,0,parentWidth,parentHeight);
 tmpCtx.fillStyle = 'blue';
 tmpCtx.fill();
 
 tmpCtx.beginPath();
 tmpCtx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius*1.5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
 tmpCtx.fillStyle = 'green';
 tmpCtx.fill();
 tmpCtx.lineWidth = 2
 tmpCtx.strokeStyle = '#003300';
 tmpCtx.stroke();
 
 tmpCtx.beginPath();
 tmpCtx.arc(parentWidth - centerX, centerY, radius*1.5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
 tmpCtx.fillStyle = 'purple';
 tmpCtx.fill();
 tmpCtx.lineWidth = 2
 tmpCtx.strokeStyle = '#003300';
 tmpCtx.stroke();
 
 tmpCtx.beginPath();
 tmpCtx.arc(parentWidth/2, parentHeight/2, radius*2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
 tmpCtx.fillStyle = 'white';
 tmpCtx.fill();
 tmpCtx.lineWidth = 2
 tmpCtx.strokeStyle = '#003300';
 tmpCtx.stroke();
 
 tmpCtx.beginPath();
 tmpCtx.arc(centerX, parentHeight - centerY, radius*1.5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
 tmpCtx.fillStyle = 'red';
 tmpCtx.fill();
 tmpCtx.lineWidth = 2
 tmpCtx.strokeStyle = '#003300';
 tmpCtx.stroke();
 
 tmpCtx.beginPath();
 tmpCtx.arc(parentWidth - centerX, parentHeight - centerY, radius*1.5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
 tmpCtx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
 tmpCtx.fill();
 tmpCtx.lineWidth = 2
 tmpCtx.strokeStyle = '#003300';
 tmpCtx.stroke();
 
 //set spacing between canvases
 var horizontalSpacing = parentWidth*0.025
 var verticalSpacing = parentWidth*0.03
 
 //initialize canvases width and height
 var widthCanvas = parentWidth*0.17;
 var heightCanvas = parentWidth*0.255;
 
 var xStart;
 var yStart = verticalSpacing;
 for(var i=0; i< 2; i++)
 {
  xStart = horizontalSpacing;
  for(var j=0; j < 5; j++)
  {
   //get specific destinationInCanvas by id and its respective context
   var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas" + ((i*5)+j));    
   var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
   
   canvas.width = widthCanvas;
   canvas.height = heightCanvas;
   
   /***!!!
   Problem next two lines
   if the next line is commented out, each canvas is drawn, but of course not translated; so you only see last canvas, canvas9
   if the next line is NOT commented out, only canvas0 is drawn and translated, the rest of the canvases 1-9 are not drawn*/
   ctx.translate(xStart, yStart);//comment out this line to see effect
   ctx.drawImage(tmpCanvas, xStart, yStart, widthCanvas, heightCanvas, 0, 0, widthCanvas, heightCanvas);
   
   xStart += (horizontalSpacing + widthCanvas);
  }
  yStart += (verticalSpacing + heightCanvas);
 }
```

```css
 #parent {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 600px;
 }

 #belowCanvas{
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-1;
 }

 #canvas0 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:0;
 }

 #canvas1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:1;
 }

 #canvas2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:2;
 }

 #canvas3 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:3;
 }

 #canvas4 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:4;
 }

 #canvas5 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:5;
 }

 #canvas6 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:6;
 }

 #canvas7 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:7;
 }

 #canvas8 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:8;
 }

 #canvas9 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:9;
 }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
   <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style-test.css">
   </head>
   <body>
  <div id="parent">
   <canvas id="belowCanvas"></canvas>
   <canvas id="canvas0"></canvas>
   <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
   <canvas id="canvas2"></canvas>
   <canvas id="canvas3"></canvas>
   <canvas id="canvas4"></canvas>
   <canvas id="canvas5"></canvas>
   <canvas id="canvas6"></canvas>
   <canvas id="canvas7"></canvas>
   <canvas id="canvas8"></canvas>
   <canvas id="canvas9"></canvas>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script-test.js"></script>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You've got some problem while incrementing `yStart` and `xStart`:
  You should do so by multiplying `heightCanvas`/`widthCanvas` by `i`/`j` state of your loop.
- Also, in your CSS, if you do add `position:absolute` without setting `margins`or `left`/`top` values, your canvases will get in stack and you'll only be able to see last one. Only add `position:absolute` to your `#belowCanvas`. Actually, if you only need a black background, you might consider wrapping all your canvases into a `div` with `background:black;`. It would be easier to align your elements then.
- Finally, you won't need `ctx.translate` since `ctx.drawImage(image, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight);` already does the translation on source image (`sx`, `sy`).

**Edit** after I talked to OP on [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71348/room-for-john-stafford):
*Actually, he wanted the canvases' holes to fit to a layout, created with a* `context.globalCompositeOperation='destination-out';`.

- I did remove the `belowCanvas` and replaced it with a `div`which background is set to black via CSS.
- To prevent ghost margins with your small canvases, you'll need to set `vertical-align:bottom; float: left` since browsers display canvas element as a character.
- I refactored the code to create the small canvases programmatically, this will allow you to change the grid format.

*For the example, I added click listener to show/hide layers:*
left click *triggers `destinationOutLayer` and* right click *triggers small canvases layer.*

```js
//get parent's width and height 
var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
var parentWidth = parent.offsetWidth;
var parentHeight = parent.offsetHeight;

var destinationOutCanvas = document.getElementById('destinationOutCanvas');
var destinationOutCtx = destinationOutCanvas.getContext('2d');

//create temporary canvas
var tmpCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var tmpCtx = tmpCanvas.getContext('2d');

//initialize width and height of temporary canvas and destOut canvas to equal parent
destinationOutCanvas.width = tmpCanvas.width = parentWidth;
destinationOutCanvas.height = tmpCanvas.height = parentHeight;


//draw temporary canvas
var centerX = parentWidth / 4;
var centerY = parentHeight / 4;
var radius = parentHeight / 4;

tmpCtx.rect(0, 0, parentWidth, parentHeight);
tmpCtx.fillStyle = 'blue';
tmpCtx.fill();

tmpCtx.beginPath();
tmpCtx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius * 1.5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
tmpCtx.fillStyle = 'green';
tmpCtx.fill();
tmpCtx.lineWidth = 2
tmpCtx.strokeStyle = '#003300';
tmpCtx.stroke();

tmpCtx.beginPath();
tmpCtx.arc(parentWidth - centerX, centerY, radius * 1.5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
tmpCtx.fillStyle = 'purple';
tmpCtx.fill();
tmpCtx.lineWidth = 2
tmpCtx.strokeStyle = '#003300';
tmpCtx.stroke();

tmpCtx.beginPath();
tmpCtx.arc(parentWidth / 2, parentHeight / 2, radius * 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
tmpCtx.fillStyle = 'white';
tmpCtx.fill();
tmpCtx.lineWidth = 2
tmpCtx.strokeStyle = '#003300';
tmpCtx.stroke();

tmpCtx.beginPath();
tmpCtx.arc(centerX, parentHeight - centerY, radius * 1.5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
tmpCtx.fillStyle = 'red';
tmpCtx.fill();
tmpCtx.lineWidth = 2
tmpCtx.strokeStyle = '#003300';
tmpCtx.stroke();

tmpCtx.beginPath();
tmpCtx.arc(parentWidth - centerX, parentHeight - centerY, radius * 1.5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
tmpCtx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
tmpCtx.fill();
tmpCtx.lineWidth = 2
tmpCtx.strokeStyle = '#003300';
tmpCtx.stroke();

//set the grid
//Strange bugs can occur with some fractions (e.g 18 rows);
var rows = 5;
var lines = 2;

//set spacing between canvases
//rounded to the nearest even number, since we divide this by 2 below
var horizontalSpacing = 2*Math.round((parentWidth*0.025)/2); // or whatever you want
var verticalSpacing = 2*Math.round((parentHeight*0.03)/2); // or whatever you want

//initialize canvases width and height
var widthCanvas = 2*(Math.round(parentWidth / rows)/2);
var heightCanvas = 2*(Math.round(parentHeight / lines)/2);

destinationOutCtx.drawImage(tmpCanvas, 0, 0);
destinationOutCtx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
destinationOutCtx.fillStyle = 'orange';

for (var i = 0; i < lines; i++) {

    for (var j = 0; j < rows; j++) {

        //get specific destinationInCanvas by id and its respective context
        //var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas" + ((i * rows) + j));

        //create the canvases on the go
        var canvas= document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = widthCanvas;
        canvas.height = heightCanvas;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        
        //only needed for the demonstration toggler
        canvas.className = "small";
        
        //set the transform variables
        var hS = horizontalSpacing/2,
            vS = verticalSpacing/2,
            xStart = (widthCanvas*j)+hS,
            yStart = (heightCanvas*i)+vS,
            cropedWidth = widthCanvas-hS*2,
            cropedHeight = heightCanvas-hS*2;


        ctx.drawImage(tmpCanvas, xStart, yStart, cropedWidth, cropedHeight, hS, vS, cropedWidth, cropedHeight);
        
        destinationOutCtx.fillRect(xStart, yStart, cropedWidth, cropedHeight);

        parent.appendChild(canvas);
    }

}

//Toggle opacity with right and left click
destinationOutCanvas.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (this.style.opacity == 0) {
        this.style.opacity = 1
    } else {
        this.style.opacity = 0
    }
});
destinationOutCanvas.style.opacity = 1;
destinationOutCanvas.addEventListener('contextmenu', function (e) {
    console.log('triggered');
    e.preventDefault();
    var smalls = document.querySelectorAll('.small');
    console.log(smalls[0].style.opacity);
    if (smalls[0].style.opacity == 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < smalls.length; i++) {
            smalls[i].style.opacity = 1
        }
    } else {
        for (i = 0; i < smalls.length; i++) {
            smalls[i].style.opacity = 0;
        };
    }
});
```

```css
#parent {
    width: 1000px !important;
    height: 600px;
    background:#000;
}
html, body {
    margin:0
}
canvas {
    vertical-align:bottom;
    float: left
}
.destinationOutLayer, #tmp {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">

</div>
  <canvas id="destinationOutCanvas" class="destinationOutLayer"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hi Kaiido, thank you for taking the time to provide me with this answer. I am working through the details now and will post a comment later. Thanks again.

Comment: I have returned to the original problem. if I could figured out how to turn this jsfiddle using destination-in (jsfiddle.net/jstafford75/…) into this jsfiddle using drawImage and translate (jsfiddle.net/jstafford75/…) that would be golden . I'll give you points and mad props

Comment: Using the drawImage and translate like here http://jsfiddle.net/jstafford75/f3frwy7f/, I would like to turn it into this using destination-in http://jsfiddle.net/jstafford75/ts26v6t7/

Comment: Kaiido, thanks for taking the time to help me on this. It is difficult to help someone when you are not sure what they are trying to accomplish. I appreciate you trying. Your suggestions of keeping my logic for iterating through my loops in one place and more concise and clear was very good . My friend Greg Bugaj here in Oklahoma City helped me get my final result I was after. It was a CSS "reset" which I had no idea how to do or how to research.